# How do I stop a daemon when the user logs out?

Tags: programming, services, logout

I wrote a daemon in C++ which is automatically started on login using a bash script placed in `/etc/profile.d/` while running the `install` section of my makefile. The problem is that when I log out and log back in, there are now two instances of the daemon running.

What I would have liked is for the first one to stop when I logged out, not keep going. It's only meant to run while somebody is logged in, anyhow. How do I make sure my daemon is not still running after I logout?

Comment: Another solution would be to modify the daemon startup and check if there is already an instance running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using D-Bus in your application, you could listen for the SessionOver signal on the org.gnome.SessionManager interface. With C++ Qt5, your code would look something like this:

```
QDBusConnection dbus = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();
dbus.connect("org.gnome.SessionManager", "",
    "org.gnome.SessionManager", "SessionOver",
    this, SLOT(handle_sessionOver());
```

References:

- [GNOME session manager documentation](https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-session/docs/gnome-session.html#org.gnome.SessionManager%3a%3aSessionOver)
- [QDBusConnection class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QDBusConnection.html) (don't forget to add "QT += dbus" to your qmake)

Comment: I have been thinking of adding D-Bus to my daemon, but I haven't done so yet. My daemon is written in C++, although it doesn't use Qt.

Comment: In addition to catching the SessionOver signal to end your application when you log out, you may also want to make your program a [single instance application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339200/how-to-create-a-single-instance-application-in-c).

Answer (score 2):

You can stop the daemon using a bash script which executes at logout

Add the following line in **lightdm.conf**

```
session-cleanup-script=<path-to-logout-bash-script>
```

lightdm.conf can be found at

- /etc/init/lightdm.conf

  **or**
- /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

This might do the job

Comment: How easy would this be to do via a `sudo make install` command, if I try to do this in my daemon's makefile? And what if I want to make it removable later using `sudo make uninstall`?